# iOS multiple threads versus groups

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have a question about threading. I have a view which displays two images (Banner of the opponents). I have read about threads groups which can run together.

The way I have it now is:

```
- (void) setBanners{
    [getBanner:@"TeamA"];
    [getBanner:@"TeamB"];
}

- getBanner:(NSString *team){
   dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
   dispatch_async(queue, ^(void){
       ..Goto server and get logo
   }
}
```

So my question is, does this happen the same way as grouping threads or does team two method get called when one is finished ? With grouping it would look like this:

```
 - setBanner{
   dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
   dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

   dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    get logo team a
   });

   dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    get logo team a
   });
  }
```

Comment: It would look like what?

Comment: Sorry added to my question

Comment: Yes, because you are not properly using a group. Where's a `dispatch_group_wait` ? Add a link to the source where you read about thread groups.

Comment: I do not need to wait on anything, they do their own work and just stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that they are almost equal.. there is no difference except that the dispatch_group reuses threads implicitly since GCD has a thread pool

-- oh and obviously GCD uses blocks